# Rectangle with curved sides and sharp corners

Tags: css, css-shapes

Is it possible to make something similar to this image with CSS? Each side of the rectangle has a curve on it. This is different to straight sides with only the border being rounded.

[image]

Comment: https://css-tricks.com/examples/ShapesOfCSS/ Check TV screen...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

TV screen 
https://css-tricks.com/examples/ShapesOfCSS/

```
#tv {
  position: relative;
  width: 200px;
  height: 150px;
  margin: 20px 0;
  background: red;
  border-radius: 50% / 10%;
  color: white;
  text-align: center;
  text-indent: .1em;
}
#tv:before {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  top: 10%;
  bottom: 10%;
  right: -5%;
  left: -5%;
  background: inherit;
  border-radius: 5% / 50%;
}
```

Comment: I don't understand. The shape here has rounded corners and your question/image specifies sharp/pointed ones.

Comment: And the title explicitly says **sharp corners**

Answer (score 6):

You can achieve the curved sides and pointed corners with the intersection of 2 oval shapes. You can use an oval div with hidden overflow and an oval pseudo element with the black background.

The pseudo element needs to be centered in it's parent. In the following example, I used absolute positioning to center it :

```css
div{
  position:relative;
  width:600px; height:150px;
  margin:0 -150px; 
  border-radius:50%;
  overflow:hidden;
}
div:after{
  content:'';
  position:absolute;
  top:-175px; left:150px;
  height:500px; width:300px;
  border-radius:inherit;
  background:#000;
}
```

```html
<div></div>
```

Answer (score -2):

You can achieve something similar using border-radius (shown below)

```
#rectangle {
    border-radius: 25px;
    padding: 20px; 
    width: 200px;
    height: 150px;    
}
```

This is a CSS3 feature. Have in mind that it only works on IE9 and up.